# Why shared-memory approach is not well suited for massive data streams?

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory

As per this [post](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-storage), which says that [emphasis mine]: Modern applications often deal with streaming data, indeed, with massively large streams of data. ***Neither the shared-file nor the shared-memory approaches are well suited for massive data streams.*** Channels of one type or another are better suited. Part 2 thus introduces channels and message queues, again with code examples in C.

My question is that why shared-memory approach is not well suited for massive data streams.Could somebody please explain that in more details?

Comment: In my opinion the claim is not true (nor false) in absolute, but it depends on context. It's true that data streams are usually sent, well, through "streams" (and message queues are an example). But in principle one could implement a stream-like channel by using shared memory and locking primitives. Performance depends on the operating system, hardware and many other things... So i think that this is an "open question", without a real "good answer" (except a very long and articulated one).

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini "It's true that data streams are usually sent, well, ***through "streams" (and message queues are an example).*** ".  Messages sent by message queues are with clear boundaries, whereas streams(say scokets) are not. So I am amazed at that, you say message queues are sent through streams. Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: What I was talking about is "common pattern" of a flow of data, regardless possible boundaries in message size, packet length etc. I was not referencing to any particular API nor implementation. I agree with you, I over-simplified the issue by including things like sockets and message queues (e.g. mq_* linux API) in the same set. They are obviously different in many ways. I was only focusing on a common behaviour, where data producer and consumer are not bound by a rigid timing. I called "stream" such a pattern and, you are right, it's  confusing and imprecise (like my english). Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory can communicate whatever data that needs to be communicated more efficiently than can message queues.  Shared memory has basically no communications overhead.  However, shared memory is limited because it can only be used to communicate with processes running on the same host.

"Massive large streams of data" are usually processed on clusters of servers.  In this case, it is more desirable to be able to spin up new processes based on the load with processes running across many servers.

A scheme could be designed that would use shared memory on the local server and networking when crossing servers, but that adds complexity.  Furthermore, if the majority of the inter-process communication is crossing servers, the extra complexity of shared memory